# Aws Api Gateway: AWS ARN for integration contains invalid action

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I try to setup basic integration between api gateway directly to my ECS backed service in VPC.

my application exposes GET /ping method that return 200 "pong" - very basic

so I ve created basic api method [image]

I am totally clueless as there are many tutorials that are describing how to integrate api-gateway with `ELB` or with `SNS` but nothing about `ECS/fargate or EC2`. but if I had to use ELB - why I need api gateway in first place :/ ?

can someone point me to any documentation?

Comment: It is very common to expose your ECS(EC2/Fargate) services directly via ELB. But API Gateway has other functionalities like throttling control. So it really depends what you need. If you just want to expose your ECS backend, ELB alone does the job.

Comment: that's fine, I though that I can limit number of elements and integrate directly gate-way with ECS service, but I understand this is not possible, right?

with ELB I could just use http integration - that's understood.

Answer (score 0):

Since your original questions sounds like you are look for documentations. Look at this . https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-with-microservices-deployed-on-amazon-ecs/

Comment: no because I ve asked whether it is possible to connect without NLB ..

Comment: Remember, ecs like ec2 , also need a load balancer. Its for high availability. In a production env, you will not find a sensible person running one docker container

Comment: true, I ll just try to save resources for basic setup with minimal requirements, that's all and paying for full-blown ELB is dominating cost